# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

I'm getting "Trying to get property of non-object" while trying to this code.

```
<?php foreach($pages as $page=>$p): ?>
<h2 class="section-title text-center wow fadeInDown"><?php echo $page[0]->title;  ?></h2>
<p class="text-center wow fadeInDown"><?php echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($page[0]->description)); ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: check the value of variable. use `print_r($pages);`.

Comment: do what @Yash says. also, instead of `$page[0]` (which accesses the first entry of an array in the current key or gets the first character of the current key if its a string) do you mean `$p` or `$page[ $p ]`?

Comment: What exactly is the value of $pages? You need to print_r($pages) and check it out.

Comment: `$page` is the current `key` & `$p` is the value.

Comment: https://ibin.co/2bspcvgxl3nR.png

Comment: Try var_dump($pages); in foreach loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change the variable $page (it´s the key) for the variable $p (The value) into the cicle.

Try this, maybe can help,

```
<?php foreach($pages as $page=>$p): ?>
<h2 class="section-title text-center wow fadeInDown"><?php echo $p->title;  ?></h2>
<p class="text-center wow fadeInDown"><?php echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($p->description)); ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed and how it solves the problem, don't just dump a bunch of code.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.
Here $pages is the object array and you have used foreach to get array values so in foreach you will get values in $p and your array key is $page.
So use $p or $p[$page].

```
<?php foreach($pages as $page=>$p): ?>
<h2 class="section-title text-center wow fadeInDown"><?php echo $p->title;  ?></h2>
<p class="text-center wow fadeInDown"><?php echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($p->description)); ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed and how it solves the problem, don't just dump a bunch of code.

Comment: use $p instead of $page[0]. @Barmar

Comment: Put that in the answer, not a comment.

Comment: And why $p instead of $page[0]?

Comment: Added brief description. @Sougata